# windows install automake fails when configuring

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin

*Update:* I am trying to install sphinxbase. But after I cd to the sphinxbase directory and run ./autogen.sh, the terminal(cygwin) tells me:

> **Error**: You must have `libtool' installed. Get ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.2.6b.tar.gz (or a newer
>   version if it is available)
>
> **Error**: You must have `automake' installed. Get ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/automake/automake-1.11.tar.gz (or a newer
>   version if it is available)

I am using cygwin to execute the configure of automake under unzipped automake directory , but I encounter this:

> User@6F-287202-NB-01
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/cpythonworkspace/sphinx/automake-1.9

```
$ ./configure --build x86_64-pc-cygwin
```

- > checking build system type... x86_64-pc-cygwin checking for a
- > BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build
- > environment is sane... yes checking for gawk... gawk checking whether
- > make sets $(MAKE)... ./configure: eval: line 1542: unexpected EOF
- > while looking for matching `"' ./configure: eval: line 1543: syntax
- > error: unexpected end of file

How to solve the **unexpected EOF** problem?

I open the configure file and jump to 1541th, 1542th line:

> # GNU make sometimes prints "make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwYYZ.png): Entering...", which would confuse us.
>   eval `${MAKE-make} -f conftest.make 2>/dev/null | grep temp=`

[notepad++ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwYYZ.png)

Comment: Could you provide a link of that file? If you have Notepad++, can you provide a screenshot of that line with "show all symbol" enabled?

Comment: Please take a look at https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ObdfMXPRzw3JDHPdfh13eUYkSL5Yn9Y/view?usp=sharing. I will install Notepad++ later

Comment: For the notepad++ screenshot, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cz98BULc20QHIZQdBnnXSLg9s6Xiz1P_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: python2-sphinx and python3-sphinx are available on cygwin. Why do you need to install from source ?

Comment: @matzeri I am not sure if sphinx and cmu-sphinx are the same thing. Initially I guess that they are different. I am trying to install cmu-sphinxbase cmu-pocketsphinx. Can you give me some ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You should put this info in your question, including how you are doing the things step by step. cmu-sphinxbase is a different project from sphinx

Comment: On my cygwin 64 bit the `unzip sphinxbase-master.zip; cd sphinxbase-master; ./autogen.sh` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `libtool` and `automake` with Cygwin setup.
You will need also `python2-devel` or `python3-devel`, `gcc-core` and `swig`

You can check after installation with:

```
$ cygcheck -cd libtool automake
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version
automake             10-1
libtool              2.4.6-6
```

The package `automake` will pull all versions of automake 1.x available. 
If other packages are reported missing, check if they already available in cygwin
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html before trying to install by source.
The following works without extra package from what available on cygwin

```
$ unzip sphinxbase-master.zip
$ cd sphinxbase-master
$ ./autogen.sh
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments.
If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
`./autogen.sh' command line.

processing .
Running libtoolize...
...
config.status: executing libtool commands
Now type `make' to compile the package.
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the cygcheck command returns only header with empty content, what might be the problems( I restart the cygwin after installing)?

Comment: I solved the abovee by using apt-cyg command; it's convenient.